# C# exe file executed hourly as windows task - needs to connect to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have inherited a C# project (exe file) that needs to run once per hour. It ran on an old server just fine, but I don't have access to that server to view the settings. I have it setup to run as a windows task. The task runs but I'm getting the error:

> System.Data.Entity exception the underlying provider failed on open - Login failed for user

SQL Server is setup for windows authentication. Websites that are running on the server which use Entity Framework connect just fine. The config file for this project is setup to authenticate the same (same setup as old server only thing I changed was the Data Source):

```
connection string=&quot;Data Source=WIN-FM8VFGOQQKN;
    Initial Catalog=DatabaseNameHere;Integrated Security=True;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient
```

The Windows task is setup to run as a Windows login account that has access to this database. I am guessing simply setting up the Windows task to run the program as a Windows login account is not enough to authenticate?

EDIT to add info: When I run the exe file from the command line logged in as the same user who is the author of the scheduled task, it runs perfectly. It only throws a .NET exception when trying to logon to SQL Server when executed as a scheduled task.

I have searched around but all I can find are solutions related to web applications. This program is not running under IIS.

Env: SQL Server 2012, asp.net 4.0, C#, Windows Server 2012 r2

Comment: Does the problem have something specific to do with it running as a task?  Does the code work if you run it standalone?  If running it as a task isn't part of the problem, please remove that from your question and tags.

Comment: What happens if you put the credentials for the user in the connection string? Do you still get the error?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - changed to just **2012**

Comment: Does it work if you login to the desktop as that user and then run the program manually?

Comment: If I run it from the command line logged on as the same user that's running the windows task it runs just fine

Comment: What options do have configured for the task? Do you have "Do not store password" checked (should not be checked if accessing network ressources)?

Comment: gus42 I have switched on and off different options. Right now I have: 
Run whether user is logged on or not and do not store password. I have toggled on and off the "run with highest priveleges" option. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You do want to store the password (i.e. per @Gus42 it's a double negative - uncheck "do not store password")..  You could also add code to log the current username - that'll prove it's running under the correct account.  Does the user account you're runninng it under have "run as batch" rights (under local security)?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755659%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: "do not store password" is unchecked. The user does have "run as batch" rights. The batch job starts to run, but a .net exception is thrown because of sql server authentication issues. The program runs fine as the same user from the command line (no authentication issues). Somehow the user account is "lost" when running the program as a batch job / scheduled task.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to go ahead and answer my own question as I couldn't find any other way around this issue. I had to change SQL Server to mixed mode authentication, create a database user, then change my connection string from windows authentication to SQL Server authentication. After that the task ran just fine. It's hard for me to believe there isn't a way around this, but I couldn't find anything. All other posts I found on the interwebs also stated they had to change to mixed mode authentication. What a waste of time!

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but for what it's worth, we have a number of programs that run as windows tasks that use integrated security without problems.

Comment: Not all of them but we have a few.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "run with highest privileges" in the scheduled task properties is set.

> > I am guessing simply setting up the Windows task to run the program as a Windows login account is not enough to authenticate?

A common problem of scheduled tasks are that the user account does not have "logon as batch" privilegs. It seems that this is not the problem here, since in the case of missing this privilege the task does not run at all.

But be aware that this privilege may be set via a GPO (group policy) from Active Directory, and this means that setting this privilege locally will be overwritten by the next GPO refresh.

And check the event log, normally problems with login / privileges missing will be logged.